# Не могу вывести данные таймера в input

Tags: angular2, binding

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="taskTitle" [(ngModel)]="taskTitle" placeholder="What are your working on?">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="project" [(ngModel)]="project">
      <option *ngFor="let project of projects" [value]="project">
      {{project}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="timerField" class="form-control" type="text" name="timer" [value]="s">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" [style.backgroundColor]="start==true?'red':'green'" (click)="timer()">{{buttonState}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let of ">
    <li>{{taskTitle}} {{project}} {{a}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>




import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      // taskTitle = 'hi';
      projects = ["timer"];
      start: boolean;
      buttonState = 'Start';
      // s: any = this.s;

      toggle() {
        this.start = !this.start;
        if(this.buttonState === 'Start') {
            this.buttonState = 'Stop'
        } else {
            this.buttonState = 'Start'
        }
      }

       timer() {
        var timeFormat = (function (){
            function num(val){
                val = Math.floor(val);
                return val < 10 ? '0' + val : val;
            }

            return function (ms/**val*/){
                var sec = ms / 1000
                  , hours = sec / 3600  % 24
                  , minutes = sec / 60 % 60
                  , seconds = sec % 60
                ;

                return num(hours) + ":" + num(minutes) + ":" + num(seconds);
            };
        })();


        // var timerField = document.getElementById('timer');
        var start = new Date;
        var timeRun = setInterval(function (){
            console.log('hi');
            this.s = timeFormat(+ new Date - + start);
            // timerField.innerHTML = timeFormat(+ new Date - + start);
        }, 1000);

        function stopTime() {
            clearInterval(timeRun);
        }
        // return this.s;

    }
    }
```

Это черновик с кучей попыток решения проблемы и кучей других проблем, если найдёте что-то неправильное помимо моего вопроса, пожалуйста подскажите, я на пороге отчаяния.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы иметь доступ к `this` вам необходимо использовать жирную стрелку

```
var timeRun = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('hi');
        this.s = timeFormat(+ new Date - + start);
        // timerField.innerHTML = timeFormat(+ new Date - + start);
    }, 1000);
```